# Difficulty plotting a two dimensional lognorm surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

here is the code im using and I've also attached the output. I'd like  to plot a two dimensional lognorm function as a 3d surface, the above code is supposed to do this however the output results in the entire plane being skewed rather than just the z values. any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
dx = 90 - (-90)
dy = 90 - (-90)
c = [dx + dx/2.0, dy+dy/2.0]
z = np.zeros((400, 400))
x = np.linspace(-90, 90, 400)
y = x.copy()
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        p =[x[i], y[j]]
        d = math.sqrt((p[0]-c[0])**2 + (p[1]-c[1])**2)
        t = d

        z[i][j] = lognorm.pdf(t, 1.2)




fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
ax.plot_surface(x,y, z, cmap = 'viridis')



plt.show()
```

**output of the provided code**

[image]

ideally I'd like for it to look something like this. 
[this is the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTlfY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to plot a 3D surface and here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018/10/25 14:44 (+0800)
# Plot a 3D surface 

from scipy.stats import norm, lognorm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

xy = np.linspace(-5, 5, 400)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(xy)
t = np.sqrt(xx**2 + yy**2)
zz = lognorm.pdf(t, 1.2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
ax.plot_surface(xx,yy, zz, cmap = 'viridis')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer i think im getting closer to the answer but i had two follow up questions one is how could i shift this so that its center is on a different value? and second how could i skew this 3d surface, such that it has a tail towards the periphery, away from 0,0 or its center point.

Comment: essentially how could i make this asymmetric looking